# Install easygui in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

I had installed easygui using pip (pip install easygui) in command prompt and it showed "Requirement already satisfied:" but in visual studio code my program cant work .It showed "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easygui'". I also got checked my pip list ,easygui is there,"easygui             0.98.2".
Can someone help me with this pls.Tqvm

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up a virtual environment where you are trying to use the module?

Did you install the module not in the virtual environment?

If you're using venv as a virtual environment and didn't install the module in the virtual environment, did you change the setting in .venv/pyvenv.cf from `include-system-site-packages = false` to `include-system-site-packages = true`?